# Add video to product gallery on productpage, using custom attribute - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, video, product-video, youtube

We would like to add video's using direct mp4 links, that we would like to load using a custom attribute on the productpage gallery.

We know the possibility to display a video on a product gallery using YouTube and Vimeo, but we do not want to upload the video's first to YouTube or Vimeo.

Is there a way to create some custom code, to add a video to the gallery?

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Of course - there is a way to reach this goal.

I think the easiest way to implement it is use custom attribute.

The plan is like below:

- add custom attribute with upload field
- prepare logic to save file on your sever
- save path to file on server
- create plugin and inject your custom attribute to `mediaGallery`
- add support for mp4 in fotorama gallery

Comment: Thanks! 

Can you help with the last two parts? How to achieve that?

Comment: You can check this about fotorama, seems interesting: https://github.com/megacarlossm/fotorama-mcsms/blob/master/README.md about creating plugin you will find a lot of information in google